# Updating a row on an Admin Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, admin

I am trying to create an Admin page which will pull up rows from a table and allow the "admin" to make changes. While I can figure out the code. I would like you to suggest me how can I display the row data and make it editable and saveable to the database. If the "admin" needs to update only the Artist Name, how do I manage that keeping the other data intact.
I just don't know how to get this done.

The Update page so far :

```
<?php
//creating MySQL connection
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','SouravBasuRoy','2525','MyteraArt');
//
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="admin-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Admin Panel: Paintings | Mytera Art</h1>
<h2>Update a Painting</h2>
<hr>

<div>
<h1>Search by Painting Name :</h1>
<form name="SearchByPainting" action="editpainting.php" method="post">
<input list="paintings" name="frompaintings">
<datalist id="paintings">
<?php
//Insert Query to extract Artist names form Database
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT `ArtName` FROM Paintings');
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<option value="' . $row['ArtName'] . '">' ;
}
?>
</datalist>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</div>
<!-- Display Area -->
<div>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['frompaintings']))
{
$item = $_POST['frompaintings'] ;

//MySQL Query to extract row by Painting Name
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Paintings WHERE `ArtName` = '$item'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<p>' . $row['ArtName'] . '</p>' ;
echo '<p>' . $row['ArtistName'] . '</p>'  ;
echo '<p>' . $row['Price'] . '</p>'  ;
echo '<p>' . $row['FileName'] . '</p>'  ;

echo '' ;
}
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The table structure is : ID  int(11) | ArtName  tinytext | ArtDescription  text | ArtistName  tinytext | ArtistDescription  text | Price  bigint(11) | FileName  varchar(5555)

Answer (score 1):

To make your data editable just type the following code (put your row as a value for html inputs)

```
<input name="ArtName" type="text" size="32" value="<?=$row['ArtName']?>">
<input accept="ArtistName" type="text" size="32" value="<?=$row['ArtistName']?>">
<input name="Price" type="text" size="32" value="<?=$row['Price']?>">
<input name="FileName" type="text" size="32" value="<?=$row['FileName']?>">
```

For update this fields you should send them using html form

```
<form action="editpainting-save.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
 <input ...>
 <input ...>
</form>
```

to editpainting-save.php with following command

```
<?
$update_query="UPDATE Paintings SET
    ArtName='".$_POST['ArtName']."',
    ArtName='".$_POST['ArtName']."',
    ArtName='".$_POST['ArtName']."',
    ArtName='".$_POST['ArtName']."'
    LIMIT 1";
$mysqli->query($update_query);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you would have to check form parameters if they are empty or not. Maybe writing a validation class, that checks if specific fields are present not empty.

Please have a look at the Laravel framework, it has a great validation class from which I believe you can learn a lot.

[Laravel](http://laravel.com/)

Comment: how should I present the data do I display it on a a table and then how do I make it editable ?